# Kotlin String variable in function parameter auto cast to java.lang.String, why?

Tags: java, string, kotlin

I just wrote some code with Kotlin, and got some problems, here is the test code:

```
fun testString(s: Any)
{
    when(s)
    {
        Int -> println("Int parameter!")
        String -> println("String parameter!")
        //Boolean -> println("Not boolean thing!") //Why Boolean cannot use in when?
        else -> println("Other object!")
    }
}

var ss = "This is actual a Kotlin String!"
println(ss.javaClass.simpleName) //out: String
testString(ss)//out: Other object! Why not String???
```

The problem is that, when just print the variable, it shows the expected output: `String (Kotlin)`, but in the `testString` function, the output one will be always the `java.lang.String`, that is why?
Then another one upsets me is that: Boolean cannot use in `when`? and why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the when-statement you will need to check wether the parameter is of type Int/String/Boolean. So the return-value needs to be a boolean.
Thus instead of `String` you need to use `is String`:

```
fun testString(s: Any)
{
    when(s)
    {
        is Int -> println("Int parameter!")
        is String -> println("String parameter!")
        is Boolean -> println("boolean thing!")
        else -> println("Other object!")
    }
}
```

Then it will also work for Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `is`

This works:

```
fun testString(s: Any)
{
    when(s)
    {
        is Int -> println("Int parameter!")
        is String -> println("String parameter!")
        is Boolean -> println("Boolean parameter!")
        else -> println("Other object!")
    }
}
```

Details: [Type Checks and Casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html)